# Heterogeneous lists and DMA

Tags: c++, heterogeneous

I'm trying to build a heterogeneous list that allocates memory to the heterogeneous array dynamically.  I'm having some trouble with the declarations necessary to make this work.  So far I have something like:

```
class Class1
{
 public:
 Class1 * GetList( int i, Class1& c );
 void Create( int size );

 private:
 Class1 ** list1;
};

class Class2: public Class1
{
  ...
};

Class1 * GetList( int i, Class1& c )
{
  return c.list1[i];
}

void Class1::Create( int size )
{
 list1 = new Class1*[size];
}

int main()
{ 
 Class1 c;
 int size = 0;

 cin >> size;

 c.Create( size );

 for( int i = 0; i < size; i ++ )
 {
    c.GetList( i, c ) = new Class2;

    c.GetList( i, c )->SetParams( some params );  
 }

}
```

I'm wondering if I'm using the heterogeneous list to store pointers of the parent class dynamically and call them in main correctly.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Class1 * GetList( int i, Class1& c );` either this function should be static, either `c` is useless and you should use `this`.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `std::vector<Class1*>` ? Is this a assignment ?

Comment: We aren't allowed to use the vector class in this assignment.  I see my mistake in the declaration of GetList.  Would something like this work: Class1 * GetList( int i )  with return list[i]; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your usage and following what we've said in the comments, you should change GetList for this:

```
Class1 *& GetList( int i )
{
 return list1[i];
}
```

Mind the `&`.  Otherwise your assignment using `GetList(i)  =...` will be useless.